# Gradle Build Error in Android Studio: "Cannot invoke method dependencyResolutionManagement() on null object"

Tags: android

**Body:**

I'm encountering a Gradle build error in my Android Studio project and need some help troubleshooting it. The error occurs when evaluating the `settings.gradle` file and seems to be related to a `NullPointerException`.

**Error Details:**

When I build the project, I receive the following error:

```
Settings file 'C:\Users\Daniel Fentahun\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\settings.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'Test1'.
Cannot invoke method dependencyResolutionManagement() on null object
```

The error points to the first line in my `settings.gradle` file. The full stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method dependencyResolutionManagement() on null object at settings_4ptt1f3ydj30an7cp2m7chco.run(C:\Users\Daniel Fentahun\AndroidStudioProjects\Test1\settings.gradle:1)
...
```

**Attempts to Resolve:**

1. I tried upgrading Gradle to the latest version.
2. I downloaded the latest SDK and APK tools.

Despite these attempts, the error persists. I'm unsure why `dependencyResolutionManagement()` is being called on a null object or how to resolve this issue.

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing this `NullPointerException` in the `settings.gradle` file?
2. Are there any specific configurations or steps I should follow to resolve this error?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show your `settings.gradle` file for better context of the issue?